# Divs are not aligning/floating with parent div properly

Tags: html, containers, parent

I have a container div around 5 other divs. The container is 960px, I want to float the first 4 divs on the left side with a width of 710px, and float the 5th and final div at the top right next to the other 4 inner divs. I've researched and tried so many different things but cannot figure out why it is floating at the bottom of the container div.

This is for myself, I'm just trying to get something up that looks decent and loads quickly. I'm no pro so please take it easy on the coding (try not to laugh too much :D )

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id=container>

<div id="menu">
<a href="index.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Those Little Stickers Home','','images/Menu Bar Images/menu_home_button_RO.png',1)">
    <img src="images/Menu Bar Images/menu_home_button.png" alt="Those Little Stickers Home Page" name="Those Little Stickers Home" width="137" height="40" border="0">
</a>
<a href="TLS iPhone 5 Sticker Gallery.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('TLS Popular','','images/Menu Bar Images/menu_stickergallery_button_RO.png',1)">
    <img src="images/Menu Bar Images/menu_stickergallery_button.png" alt="See What's Popular" name="TLS Popular" width="137" height="40" border="0">
</a>
<a href="TLS Accessories Page.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('TLS Accessories','','images/Menu Bar Images/menu_accessories_button_RO.png',1)">
    <img src="images/Menu Bar Images/menu_accessories_button.png" alt="TLS Accessories Phone cases, bumpers, and much more" name="TLS Accessories" width="137" height="40" border="0">
</a>
<a href="TLS Select Your Device to Customize.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Select by Device','','images/Menu Bar Images/menu_selectbydevice_button_RO.png',1)">
    <img src="images/Menu Bar Images/menu_selectbydevice_button.png" alt="Select by Device" name="Select by Device" width="137" height="40" border="0">
</a>
<a href="TLS A Little About Us.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('TLS A Little About Us','','images/Menu Bar Images/menu_alittleabout_button_RO.png',1)">
    <img src="images/Menu Bar Images/menu_alittleabout_button.png" alt="A Little About Those Little Stickers" name="TLS A Little About Us" width="137" height="40" border="0">
</a>
<a href="TLS Customize Your Device.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Create Your Own','','images/Menu Bar Images/menu_create_your_own_button_RO.png',1)">
    <img src="images/Menu Bar Images/menu_corporate_button.png" alt="Create Your Own Little Sticker Design" name="Create Your Own" width="137" height="40" border="0">
</a>
<a href="TLS Contact.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Contact Us','','images/Menu Bar Images/menu_contact_button_RO.png',1)">
    <img src="images/Menu Bar Images/menu_contact_button.png" alt="Contact Us" name="Contact Us" width="137" height="40" border="0">
</a>
</div>

<div id="header_container">

<div id="about_us_header">

  <h1>iPhone 5/5s Little Sticker Gallery</h1>
    Make your iPhone as unique as you are with our wide selection
    of custom designed Little Stickers. The clear adhesive sticker covers and protects the
    brushed metal on the back of your iPhone while the custom designs give it a unique style
    just like you. Add a bumper to your Little Sticker and save some money.
    There's billions of devices out there, be different.
    <br>
</div>
</div>


<div id="gallery_container">

<div id="gallery_pics1">

<a href="TLS iPhone 5 Jordan Crowd Dunk.html"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/Jordan_Crowd_blackongold_iPhone5.png" width="170" height="322" class="hoverImage"></a><a href="TLS iPhone 5 Jordan Dunk.html"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/Jordan-Dunk_blackongold_iPhone-5.png" width="170" height="322" class="hoverImage"></a><a href="TLS iPhone 5 The Giving Tree.html"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/The-Giving-Tree_grayongold_iPhone-5.png" width="170" height="323" border="0" class="hoverImage"></a><a href="TLS iPhone 5 Snow White Apple Bite.html"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/Snow-White_grayongold_iPhone5.png" width="170" height="323" class="hoverImage"></a>

</div>

<div id="gallery_pics2">

<a href="TLS iPhone 5 Snow White Bandana G.html"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/Snow-White-G_grayonwhite_iPhone-5.png" width="170" height="324" class="hoverImage"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/Snow-White-Zombie_blackongoldl_iPhone5.png" width="170" height="324" class="hoverImage"></a><a href="TLS iPhone 5 Elvira Sideways.html"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/Elvira-Sideways2 edit_GOLDwithBLACK_iPhone5.png" width="340" height="324" class="hoverImage"></a>

</div>

<div id="gallery_pics3">

    <a href="#"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/The-Munsters_blackongold_iPhone5.png" width="170" height="324" class="hoverImage"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/Bride-of-Frankenstein_grayongold_iPhone5.png" width="170" height="324" class="hoverImage"></a><a href="TLS iPhone 5 The Beatles Crosswalk.html"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/Beatles-Crosswalk_grayongold_iPhone5.png" alt="The Beatles Crosswalk Little Sticker for iPhone 5 and 5s" width="170" height="324" class="hoverImage"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/Chucky-OG_blackonwhite_iPhone5.png" width="170" height="324" class="hoverImage"></a>

    </div>

    <div id="gallery_pics4">

    <a href="#"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/Devils-Rejects-Captain-Spaulding_blackongold_iPhone5.png" width="170" height="324" class="hoverImage"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/Pennywise-IT-Face_grayongold_iPhone5.png" width="170" height="324" class="hoverImage"></a><a href="TLS iPhone 5 Space Invaders.html"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/Space_Invaders_grayongold_iPhone5.png" width="170" height="323" class="hoverImage"></a><a href="TLS iPhone 5 Hand Hearts.html"><img src="images/Optimized Images/iPhone 5/Hand-Hearts_grayongold_iPhone5.png" width="170" height="324" class="hoverImage"></a>
</div>

<div id="categories">

<br>
<a href="TLS iPhone 5 Sticker Gallery.html"> Little Shop of Horrors</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="TLS iPhone 5 Sticker Gallery.html" title="New Little Stickers">New Little Stickers</a>
<br>
<br>
 <a href="#">Charity Little Stickers </a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="TLS Customize Your Device.html">Create Your Own Sticker</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="TLS iPhone 5 Bumper Case.html">iPhone 5 Accessories</a>
<br>

<br>
<br>

<img src="images/categories banner.png" width="215" height="238">
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">

    <span style="vertical-align: middle; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; font-size: 14px;">Copywright &#169 2013 Those Little Stickers Inc. All rights reserved. Designed and located in Hermosa Beach, CA</span>    

    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/thoselittlestickers" target="_new"><img src="images/facebook_button.jpg" alt="Those Little Stickers Facebook Page" width="38" height="36" border="0" align="absmiddle"  style="vertical-align: middle; "></a>

    <a href="https://twitter.com/LittleStickers" target="_new"><img src="images/twitter_button.jpg" alt="Those Little Stickers Twitter Page" width="38" height="36" border="0" align="absmiddle" style="vertical-align: middle;"></a>

    <a href="http://pinterest.com/LittleStickers/" target="_new"><img src="images/pinterest_button.jpg" alt="Those Little Stickers Pinterest Page" width="38" height="36" border="0" align="absmiddle" style="vertical-align: middle;"></a>

    <a href="http://thoselittlestickers.wordpress.com/" target="_new"><img src="images/wordpress_button.jpg" alt="Those Little Stickers Wordpress Page" width="38" height="36" border="0" align="absmiddle"  style="vertical-align: middle;"></a>

    <img src="images/youtube_button.jpg" alt="Those Little Stickers YouTube Page" width="38" height="36" border="0" align="absmiddle" style="vertical-align: middle;">

</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

a img.hoverImage{
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

a img.hoverImage:hover{
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 2px #CCC;
}

a img.socialmedia:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 3px #ccc;
    border-radius:50px;
}

a:link {
    color: #999;
}
a:visited {
    color: #3CF;
}
a:active {
    color: #999;
}

/* div styles */

#container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#menu   {
    width:960px;
    float:left;
}

#header_container {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 960px;
    border: solid #999 1px;
    clear:left;
}

#about_us_header {
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    width:670px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #777;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-bottom:10px;

}

#gallery_container {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width: 960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: solid #999 1px;
    position:relative;
}

#gallery_pics1 {
    float:left;
    width:710px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-bottom: solid #999 1px;
    border-right:solid #999 1px;
}

#gallery_pics2 {
    float:left;
    width:710px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-bottom: solid #999 1px;
    border-right:solid #999 1px;
    clear:left;
}

#gallery_pics3 {
    float:left;
    width:710px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-bottom: solid #999 1px;
    border-right:solid #999 1px;
    clear:left;
}

#gallery_pics4 {
    float:left;
    width:710px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-bottom: solid #999 1px;
    border-right:solid #999 1px;
    clear:left;
}

#categories {
    clear:none;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#333;
    text-align:right;
    width:220px;
    float:right;
}

#footer {
    width:960px;
    float:left;
    clear: left;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    border-top: solid #999 1px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    border-bottom: solid #999 1px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

#site_map_footer {
    float:left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    clear: both;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap them in separate divs - http://jsfiddle.net/1pfugm6n/

```
<div id="left">
....
</div>
<div id="right">
....
</div>


#left {
   float: left;
}
#right {
   float: right
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! That worked perfectly. That is the only thing I didn't try yet. I didn't even enter the css for them yet, just the divs in html and it already worked. Adding the css now. Thanks again, you have no idea how happy and thankful I am!!!!

Comment: Glad to help :) You can accept my answer if you think it was good enough even when I posted unnecessary css :)

Comment: Sorry I'm a rookie. I thought adding a 1 up was it and it wouldn't allow me, but I found the check mark. I'll gladly accept that answer!! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to position the `categories` div absolutely:

```
#categories {
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#333;
    text-align:right;
    width:220px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: According to numerous articles I read on trying to fix it they all basically said the same thing you did so I'm assuming it is correct. Unfortunately it did not fix it for me though. However I really appreciate the feedback and time to reply!